# Dropwizard IntelliJ Setup Issue

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I'm trying to setup Dropwizard hello world application and running into an issue. Here is the stack trace:

```
objc[30585]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1021cc4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1031fd4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TreeTraversingParser.<init>(TreeTraversingParser.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TreeTraversingParser.<init>(TreeTraversingParser.java:65)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationFactory.build(ConfigurationFactory.java:125)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationFactory.build(ConfigurationFactory.java:77)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:114)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:63)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72)
    at com.example.HelloWorldApplication$.main(HelloWorldApplication.scala:18)
    at com.example.HelloWorldApplication.main(HelloWorldApplication.scala)
```

Here is my Application:

```
package com.example

import io.dropwizard.Application
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment

class HelloWorldApplication extends Application[HelloWorldConfiguration] {
  override def run(configuration: HelloWorldConfiguration, environment: Environment): Unit = {
    val helloWorld = new HelloWorldResource()
    environment.jersey().register(helloWorld)
  }

  override def initialize(bootstrap: Bootstrap[HelloWorldConfiguration]): Unit = {}
}

object HelloWorldApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    new HelloWorldApplication().run(args)
  }
}
```

I run the application with these arguments in IntelliJ: `server src/main/resources/config.yml`

Any tips to debug and get set up properly would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a jar file in the Scala project by going to Project Structure > Artifacts and adding a project jar.